# Arguing that $\int_0^1 f = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^1 f$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\ge 0$, my professor said that you could use $\int_0^1 f = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^1 f$, due to the Monotone Convergence Theorem. In this case, is it because the functions are actually $g_n(x) = \int_{h_n}^1f$ (where $h_n$ is a sequence that tends to $0$)? If so, the MCT states that, if there exist functions $f_1 \leq f_2 \leq ...$ such that $f_n \to f$ then $\int f_n \to \int f$, but in the example with $g_n \to g$ there is no integral (since it is "included" in the function $g_n$).

Comment: Is $f$ suppose to be integrable? There is not enough hypothesis to prove the result.

Comment: I already got my answer. Thanks.

Comment: It answers my question.

Comment: Yes it does. This question is not about how the MCT works. It is implied that they are positive, which is necessary for MCT to work. I was just asking for a clarification because I misunderstood which were the functions $f_n$ of the theorem in the example given. Which is exactly what was answered.

Comment: Please, be aware that questions have to be made so they can be used as a reference for future users, not only for you. So you need to make the statement as clear as possible. Mathematics are already difficult enough to learn.

Comment: Seconding @KaboMurphy's point. We would need to know that $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ for the result to go through. There are functions $f$ where the limit doesn't exist even though $\int_\epsilon^1 f$ exists for every $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins At this point in the edits, we have the assumption that $f \geq 0,$ so we only need $f$ measurable, not necessarily integrable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using indicator functions, we may write
$$\int_\epsilon^1 f = \int_0^1 f \cdot \mathbf{1}_{[\epsilon,1]}$$
Then we may define $g_n(x) = f \cdot \mathbf{1}_{[h_n,1]}$ for some decreasing sequence $h_n$ tending to $0.$